# How to achieve Full text Search in Linq (.net 4.0)

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have been struggling to get a possible way to achieve filtering my result sets on certain criterions one of them being Full Text Search. After skimming few blogs came to know Linq doesnt directly supports it and there is a [work around](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/simons/archive/2008/12/18/LINQ-to-SQL---Enabling-Fulltext-searching.aspx) which made sense.

So I started with that approach but hit a dead end when it occurred to me I cannot use table valued functions in .net 4.0 (.net 4.5 does support though which I cannot use (function import) as of now).

Then I come across another [work around](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/96457/Defining-Custom-Functions-in-Entity-Framework) to use custom functions by editing ssdl file and add function details (using commandtext for custom query).

My UDF looks like below :-

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_CandidateFTS
(   
    @keywords nvarchar(4000)
)
RETURNS @resCandidates TABLE
(
    CandidateID INT,
    FileRank INT
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @resCandidates
    (
        CandidateID,
        FileRank
    )
    SELECT c.CandidateID, fileContent.Rank as FileRank
            FROM CONTAINSTABLE (FileContent, Content, @keywords) as fileContent
            INNER JOIN [file] f on f.ContentID = fileContent.[Key]
            INNER JOIN [Candidate_Resume] c on c.CandidateID = f.[ID]

    RETURN
END
```

I edited my SSDL file :-

```
 <Function Name="GetCandidateWithTextSearch" IsComposable="false">
    <CommandText>
      SELECT * from
      dbo.udf_CandidateFTS(@keywords)
    </CommandText>
    <Parameter Name="keywords" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
  </Function>
```

And added a EDMFunction :-

```
    public class MyFunctions
    {
        [EdmFunction("MMJ.Service.Data", "GetCandidateWithTextSearch")]
        public static IList GetCandidateWithTextSearch(string keywords)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
```

And along with other filters i want to do the following :-

```
 var query = context.Candidate
.Where(c => c.ID.Equals(MyFunctions.GetCandidateWithTextSearch("wali")
.Contains(c.ID))).ToList();
```

Kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work. The first workaround is using mapped table valued function - it requires .NET 4.5. The second workaround is using mapping equivalent to stored procedure. The differences between those two are:

- The first is composable. It can be used in Linq-to-entities queries and is translated to SQL function call.
- The second is not composable. It can be just executed and enumerated. Everything else must run in your application as Linq-to-objects.

In .NET 4.0 the best option is to use the second approach and write the whole SQL query in `DefiningQuery` section (you cannot add more conditions from your application). Or simply create stored procedure and map it through designer.

Comment: There were simply lot of issues with integrating with linq... i made a Stored proc and am doing it old ADO.net way... disappointed...